# Double Slit: Collected Data Versus Gedanken

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, experimental-technique

To frame my question, I'd like to present two example quotes from articles on the double slit experiment written in respected (or at least widely read) publications:

One from [Quanta](https://www.quantamagazine.org/famous-experiment-dooms-pilot-wave-alternative-to-quantum-weirdness-20181011/):

> Stranger still, when you add a second sensor and detect which slit each particle passes through, the interference stripes disappear, as if the probability wave, known as the wave function, has collapsed. This time, particles pass straight through their chosen slits to either of two spots on the far sensor.

And one from [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-018-05892-6):

> The particles seem to interfere with themselves. Odder, the pattern vanishes if we use a detector to measure which slit the particle goes through: it’s truly particle-like, with no more waviness. Oddest of all, that remains true if we delay the measurement until after the particle has traversed the slits (but before it hits the screen). And if we make the measurement but then delete the result without looking at it, interference returns.

Here's my question: can someone tell me exactly which (ideally modern) experimental results are being referenced here? I understand you can put polarizers at 90 degrees from each other on each slit (effectively "measuring" which slit light passes through), but I'm guessing there are more modern tests that have been done which provide less disruptive measurements and show the same result. Essentially I want to know what professional physicists consider to be the state of the art on demonstrating this phenomenon in an unequivocal way. Especially important to me is where the line is between thought experiment, and actual data.

The bigger problem for me in this question is the assertion in the Nature article *"if we make the measurement but then delete the result without looking at it, interference returns."* I see these sorts of statements made frequently without references cited. Is this actually a tested result, or is this a thought experiment? Obviously articles written for lay audiences will tend to oversimplify things for brevity, but this one seems particularly blurry to me. Can someone provide a reference paper for this?

**Postscript**

The [Wikipedia page for the double slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#cite_note-Mittelstaedt-43) references two papers(^1)(^2) which demonstrate that you can at least partially measure on the slits and still maintain an interference pattern. As I understand it, this agrees just fine with the predictions, but it does in my very lay-person opinion make the latter quote sound particularly facile.

<sub>1: P. Mittelstaedt; A. Prieur; R. Schieder (1987). "Unsharp particle-wave duality in a photon split-beam experiment". Foundations of Physics. 17 (9): 891–903.</sub>

<sub>2: D.M. Greenberger and A. Yasin, "Simultaneous wave and particle knowledge in a neutron interferometer", Physics Letters A 128, 391–4 (1988).</sub>

Comment: Hi Jon, Welcome to Physics SE! :) _"And if we make the measurement but then delete the result without looking at it, interference returns."_ -- this claim is simply wrong as you rightly suspect. This is a widely spread mischaracterization of some combination of the quantum eraser experiment and Wheeler's delayed choice experiment. Rest assured, if the results of measuring the "which-slit information" were saved on your computer and I burn your hard disk, the interference pattern won't be gone. I will try to pen down a more elaborate answer later today.

Comment: Thanks @DvijD.C.! Look forward to hearing more if and when you get around to it. I'm of course not surprised to hear that this claim is false, I am surprised that Nature would publish something including this claim. I can only speculate what the author had in mind when writing it, or the editors when they let it go through to publication. Generally speaking Nature is among the more respected scientific journals out there.